# Expressing the solution of an initial value problem as an integral.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have the following IVP

$$ x \frac{ d }{dx} \left( x \frac{d}{dx} - 1 \right) \left( x \frac{ d }{dx} -2  \right)\left( x \frac{ d }{dx} -3  \right) y(x) = f(x) $$

$y(1)=y'(1)=y''(1)=y'''(1)=0$

IS there a way to the express the solution to this IVP as an integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us use the notation
\begin{align}
A_k = x\frac{d}{dx}-k
\end{align}
then the above differential equation could be rewritten as
\begin{align}
A_0A_1A_2A_3 y = f. \ \ (*)
\end{align}
For later convenience, let us compute the commutator of $[A_k, A_\ell]$ for $k, \ell = 0, \ldots, 3$. Observe
\begin{align}
[A_k, A_\ell]  =&\ \left[x \frac{d}{dx}-k, x \frac{d}{dx}-\ell\right] = 
\left[x\frac{d}{dx} , x\frac{d}{dx}\right]- \left[k, x\frac{d}{dx}\right] - \left[x\frac{d}{dx}, \ell\right]+[k, \ell]=0
\end{align}
which means the $A_k$ commutes with each other.

Let begin by solving the homogeneous problem
\begin{align}
A_0A_1A_2A_3 y = 0.
\end{align}
But then it suffices to solve
\begin{align}
A_k y = x\frac{dy}{dx}-k y = 0  \ \ (**)
\end{align}
since the $A_k$ commutes. Solving $(\ast \ast)$ yields the solutions
\begin{align}
y_k = t^k.
\end{align}
Hence the general solutions of $A_0A_1A_2A_3 y = 0$ is given by
\begin{align}
y(t) = c_0+c_1t+c_2t^2+c_3t^3. 
\end{align}
Given we have the homogeneous initial conditions $y(1) = y'(1) = y''(1) = y'''(1)= 0$, then it follows the solutions to the inhomogeneous problem is given by
\begin{align}
y(t) = \int^t_1 G(t, s) f(s)\ ds
\end{align}
where $G(t, s)$ is the Green's function associated to the operator $A_0A_1A_2A_3$. We can explicitly compute $G(t, s)$ which is given by the formula
\begin{align}
G(t, s)= \frac{1}{W[y_0, y_1, y_2, y_3](s)}
\begin{vmatrix}
y_0(s) & y_1(s) & y_2(s) & y_3(s)\\
y_0'(s) & y_1'(s) & y_2'(s) & y_3'(s)\\
y_0''(s) & y_1''(s) & y_2''(s) & y_3''(s)\\
y_0(t) & y_1(t) & y_2(t) & y_3(t)
\end{vmatrix}=\frac{-2s^3+6ts^2-6t^2s+2t^3}{12}.
\end{align}

Hence your solution is given by
\begin{align}
y(t) = \int^t_1 \frac{-2s^3+6ts^2-6t^2s+2t^3}{12}f(s)\ ds.
\end{align}